# Illegal string offset issue with wotpress plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a problem with wordpress plugin, whenever I try to save config it says its saved but nothing is being saved.

```
[05-Mar-2018 07:40:55 UTC] PHP Warning:  Illegal string offset 'show_photos' in /mnt/web217/a0/48/51614848/htdocs/WordPress_03/wp-content/plugins/team-rosters/includes/mstw-tr-settings.php on line 283
```

this is the debug.log

```
$output[$key] = ( sanitize_text_field( $input[$key] ) == $input[$key] ) ? $input[$key] : $output[$key];
```

and this is the line number 283, any idea how to fix this or whats causing the issue?

@fonini

> Array ( [show_photos] => 1 [photo_label] => Photo [show_number] => 1
>   [number_label] => Nbr [name_label] => Name [show_position] => 1
>   [position_label] => Pos [show_height] => 1 [height_label] => Ht
>   [show_weight] => 1 [weight_label] => Wt [show_year] => 0 [year_label]
>   => Year [show_experience] => 0 [experience_label] => Exp [show_age] => 0 [age_label] => Age [show_home_town] => 0 [home_town_label] => Home
>   Town [show_last_school] => 0 [last_school_label] => Last School
>   [show_country] => 0 [country_label] => Country [show_bats_throws] => 0
>   [bats_throws_label] => Bat/Thw [show_other_info] => 0
>   [other_info_label] => Other )

this is the result I get from printr $input

And $output is

> O

Comment: Try to print_r() the $input and $output variables to see if the 'show_photos' index exists. Probably not.

Comment: @fonini I get such a result - check main post

Comment: And what is `$output`?

Comment: $outpit is equa to O

Answer (score -1):

When debugging ternary expressions, it is ALWAYS helpful to break them out onto separate lines so that PHP can more precisely guide you to the offending code:

Try:

```
$output[$key] = (
    sanitize_text_field(
        $input[$key]
    ) ==
    $input[$key] ) ?
    $input[$key] :
    $output[$key]; // <-- your issue is probably here
```

After you have debugged your issue then you can change it back into a one-liner.